# Do monsters endlessly respawn in Lara Croft & The Guardian of Light?

Tags: lara-croft-the-guardian-of-light

I've returned to an area of the level I've already visited and a new patch of monsters emerged from the ground, similar to the batch I've originally encountered in that area. Does this mean that monsters endlessly respawn when continually re-visiting areas, or is there a limit to the number of spawns?

If the respawn is unlimited, does it also mean that revisiting areas is a good way to reach higher scores by killing more and more monsters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "emerged from the ground" then it sounds like you are talking about skeletons. You can't kill them with bullets, only with explosives. When you kill them with bullets they get reborn a few seconds later, and you get no points for this.

Other than that I don't remember any places where monsters would respawn endlessly, only during some boss battles.